# Looking for 1970's UFO movie with underwater base

Tags: story-identification, movie, ufos

What was the movie where there was an underwater UFO base?  I think it was a feature-length film, in color, as I definitely saw it a theater in the mid to late '70s.  Don't remember if it was Japanese or not.

I think the UFOs were classic saucers, without any big periscope or any attachments like the War of the Worlds had.  In one scene, a UFO is flying along the ocean, and then decends and splashes right into the water!  Then it is coasting along undersea, and enters through a rocky doorway or cave?  Maybe?

Thanks to the people who have responded already, still not what I remember.  Darn I wish I could remember more.

Comment: Not this, I assume - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWh3MbgfgOg

Answer (score 9):

It may be the 1970 TV series *[UFO](http://ufoseries.com/)*. You can watch episode 1 on YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQtuowj2GvM). There's an underwater launch of one of the good guy's UFO interceptors at about 29:00 and an encounter with one of the flying saucers at about 30:20. The good guys use submarine bases, I don't remember why. Although a british show, it has several Japanese characters and looks a bit like a "Gozilla"-type production.

Comment: Thank you Richard and Joe L.  I definitely saw it in a movie theater, and I think it was a feature length film.  I remember the UFO being a sleek and shiny saucer, and flying from right to left before splashing into the ocean.

Comment: Both UFO and it's sequel Space 1999 had film versions (really episodes edited together into a cinema length) and a cinema release, certainly in non-UK markets

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager I never considered Space 1999 a sequel of UFO... I remember I quite liked Space 1999 and quite hated UFO --- and it seems to me they were quite unrelated. Am I wrong?

Comment: According to accounts UFO season 2 was to expand moonbase and be based there.  Lew Grade pulled the plug on season 2 when the US ratings dipped, but Gerry Anderson pitched reusing the work for UFO2 as Space 1999.  There are also some common elements, both have uprisings defeating racism in the late 70s etc.  So it's not absolute but Gerry Anderson and others have implied it over the years.

Answer (score 9):

Could it be the movie [Starship Invasions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Invasions)?

**Update:** As it appears this is the answer, I will expand for future readers.

The movie involves the Bad Guys flying to Earth in order to find a new home as their own planet is about to explode. Unfortunately for them, Earth is under the production of the Intergalactic Good Guys, who live in a huge golden pyramid under the ocean. Bad Guys fly to said pyramid, which they enter through a large portal that glows with the internal light when opened. Hilarity follows.

[image: UFO approaching underwater pyramid]
[image: image of UFO hangar inside the pyramid, showing two UFO designs]

Comment: Welcome! Can you specify *why* you think this answer is correct?

Comment: The movie has an underwater base in the shape of a [pyramid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QESnwxRUxyw#t=1119).

Comment: Holy moly.  I think that was it!  Like Nilla wafers, I thought it was freaking awesome when I was a kid.

Comment: And the "classic UFO"s part is the other giveaway - the movie deliberately based its models on various UFO reports.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe [Raumpatrouille – Die phantastischen Abenteuer des Raumschiffes Orion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raumpatrouille_%E2%80%93_Die_phantastischen_Abenteuer_des_Raumschiffes_Orion)?

The show had flying saucers that operate out of underwater bases.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly a movie about UFOs, but this description reminds me of [Atragon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atragon).  This would be an exact match for the given description.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility could be "City Beneath the Sea"; the follow up of "Voyage to the Bottom of the Sea".  I think that they are UFOs in this one, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Oh man I had forgotten about this one. I've got to track it down now.  Vaults of gold bricks protecting radioactive stuff! Flying subs!  Don't remember UFOs though.