# Underwater sci fi movie in English but with italian actors or director

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a science fiction movie (with some type of Italian influence) about an underwater community that runs into some type of problem. I am older, and this movie could date from around the 70's or 80's. I cannot swear to this, since some of the Italian movies made for American distribution are hard to identify.

Comment: any more details you can provide here? Was this a theatrical movie or TV movie? Where did you see it? Can you remember anything about the actors/actresses/etc? Every little bit helps.

Comment: Could the answers to this question help? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73412/looking-for-1970s-ufo-movie-with-underwater-base

Comment: You can accept my answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

This could be the Italian-produced but English language movie *[The Raiders of Atlantis](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086135/)*.

Per IMDB:

> A team of scientists working to raise a sunken Russian nuclear submarine on an ocean platform off the coast of Miami, Florida, unearth an ancient Atlantean relic from the sea floor and bring in an expert to make some sense of it. But while attempting to raise the sub, radioactive leakage from its missles triggers the re-emergence of Atlantis, and the resulting tidal wave destroys the platform and leaves only a small group of survivors. Rescued by two Vietnamvets-turned-heavies who are out relaxing after their latest job, their boat eventually runs aground on a Carribean island nearby where, upon going ashore, it is discovered that everything has been destroyed and everybody killed. The culprits, a vicious group of well-armed raiders, and their leader, Crystal Skull, are descendants of Atlantis' original race who set about reclaiming the world and adding the survivors to the list of victims as they struggle to stay alive and defeat the raiders and send Atlantis back to the ocean floor.

It's not very good.

---

This has been confirmed by the original questioner (ColleenCervantes) in [a deleted answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/191893/54887). Screenshot for <10k rep users can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPa6g.png).

Comment: Fixed the mis copied quote and removed your opinion about the film, that's not needed here.

Comment: Can you expand on why you re-edited your opinion of the film in?

Comment: I can't speak for Buzz, but in general, we give people a lot of leeway for adding their opinions in addition to the facts as long as they make it clear which is which.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I see no reason why story identification questions cannot include information about the quality, availability, etc. of a particular work.  It's just additional, potentially useful information.  In this case, this was a film that seemed ok when I was a kid, but was pretty bad when I re-watched some of it as an adult.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - I'm with Buzz on this one. We remove *meaningless* chatter (like "I hope you enjoy it").